# Link Clicked Change Button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a link and i put a button (pic) for it and i want when the link is clicked the button (pic) change like the visited links when it turns to purple

```
<td><a id="download" href="<?=$row['download_link']?>" target="_blank"><img src="download.png"></a></td>
```

can it be changed in html or have to do something in css and what is it

[image] to [image: downloaded]

Comment: Yes, can be changed. Search "javascript swap image"

Comment: @Gerben jacobs You can do this in plain CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in plain CSS by removing the `img` from the `a`, and adding the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #download 
    {
      background-image:url(download.png);
      display:block;
      /* todo : put height and width of image here */
      width:100px; 
      height:100px;
    }

    #download :visited
    {
      background-image:url(download_visited.png);
    }
</style>
```

Comment: i have to give the link an id="download"

Comment: have to put this <style> ?

Comment: `<Style>` tags go in the `<head>` section